# Why should I (void) the return of memset()?

Tags: c, casting, void, suppress-warnings, memset

When I was looking for some inspiration, I stumbled across the following code:

```c
(void)memset(&ifm, 0, sizeof(ifm));
```

https://github.com/i3/i3status/blob/master/src/print_eth_info.c#L55

I know (void) cast is used to suppress unused warnings in C.
But I don't see any reason why a warning should be generated for not checking the return value of memset().

So may question is what is the reason for using void cast here.

Comment: There's no need to do it, and most programmers don't.

Comment: It might be useful if you enable warnings about not using the results of functions.

Comment: When you compile with `-Wall`, some/most warnings are enabled. Normally, `(void)` is not needed _unless_ you compile with `-Wunused-result` which _is_ enabled by default. But, you only get a warning if a given function is marked with the attribute "warn_unused_result" (per `man gcc`). So, normally, don't just add `(void)` unless you _have_ to, IMO

Comment: @TonyTannous I guess this could be the reason. Thank you. Although its pretty obvious that the return of memset() can savely be ignored

Comment: @CraigEstey I thought about the same, but I don't see any reason to mark memset as "warn_unuesed_result".

Comment: @Schafwolle what might seem obvious to oneself, may not be for someone else.

Comment: I just blamed the file the (void) cast was introduced 11 years ago

Comment: Basically, it's up to the discretion of the author of the _called_ function whether to use the attribute or not. Most functions _don't_ do this. So, using `(void)` is to _override_ those _rare_ ones that do. It says [effectively] "I know I don't use the return value and I _know_ it's okay". If this were a problem, I'd just add `-Wno-unused-result` to my makefile. Again, IMO, using `(void)` is just cruft, and makes the code _less_ readable. The compiler checks this now. IIRC, before you had to do: `int dummy; dummy = fnc();` or a special comment to get `lint` to shut up

Comment: This might be useful if the an author changes a function signature from `void myfunc(void)` to `int myfunc(void)` [say 6 months later]. Not recommended practice if `myfunc` API has been published for an extended period of time. But, the [linux] kernel developers are willing to do such things (with justification) rather than leave bad code in the code base.

Comment: `struct ifmediareq ifm;
    (void)memset(&ifm, 0, sizeof(ifm));` would have been cleaner as `struct ifmediareq ifm = { 0 };`. AFAIK, not only is the `(void)` unnecessary, the `memcpy()` is also avoidable.

Comment: VTC as dupe as " what is the reason for using void cast here." is "you ignore the return value, and did not just forget it." in the dupe.  Certainly this is more valuable in functions like `scanf()` and family than in `mem..(a...), str...(a,...)` that always return `a`.